# pymssql - use only password from windows authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymssql

So, I have two servers:

1) Dev

2) Prod

I am using `pymssql.connect()` for connecting to a SQL database to which `Dev\user` has access. The problem is that `Prod\user` does not have access, but it is the same password to login to both servers, thus if I could do something like, on the "prod" server

```
user = input("user:")
pymssql.connect("select 2",server_db,user=user,password=None)
```

then I can hard type `user=dev\user` and still use the password from authentication, which does not work. If I set `user=None`, then automatically `user` and `pw` is from the authentication, but is it not possible to extract either of those?

I cannot type the password since it is a job which runs each night.

Comment: You can store the usernames and passwords in a separated file (JSON for example), then in your script you can select the user or password depending on the host name

Comment: That is really insecure